# How to eliminate the blue focus on ToolStripDropDownButton when mouse is above the control

Tags: c#, focus, mouse, toolstripdropdown

I use **ToolStripDropDownButton** with **Forecolor** is **white** and **Backcolor** is **trasparent**. Text of "ToolStripDropDownButton" unreadable when mouse is above the control because "blue focus" is visible.

How to eliminate/remove the "**blue focus"** on **ToolStripDropDownButton** when mouse is above the control? Looks like the picture below. Thank You.

[image]
Which produces output like digEmAll picture.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           toolStrip1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
           toolStrip1.GripStyle = ToolStripGripStyle.Visible;
           toolStrip1.Renderer = new MyRenderer();
       }

       private class MyRenderer : ToolStripSystemRenderer
       {
          protected override void OnRenderArrow(ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e)
          {
              e.ArrowColor = Color.White;
              base.OnRenderArrow(e);
          }

          protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
          {
             // remove white line bellow button (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/92862/toolstrip-always-draws-a-border-on-the-bottom-with-rendermode-system-and-docked-left-or-right)
             //base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Renderer property of the `ToolStrip`. For example using `ToolStripSystemRenderer` instead of the default `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` :

```
this.toolStrip.Renderer = new ToolStripSystemRenderer();
```

you'll get the following result:

[image]

If you want to customize it more heavily, you can extend ToolStripSystemRenderer. For example with the following code you can change the color of the arrow:

```
class MyRenderer : ToolStripSystemRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderArrow(ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ArrowColor = Color.White;
        base.OnRenderArrow(e);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I tried your program, the output looks like the your picture but have a white line under the button, how to hide the white line, thanks.

Comment: @user705654: I didn't understand you want to completely erase any button highlighting. To do that, have a look to Hans Passant's answer ;)

Comment: I want output like your picture, but after I run your program, which produces output like this http://i43.tinypic.com/2i9pjww.jpg. How to hide the white line under button.

Comment: @ digEmAll, I found the answer, white line that appears below the buttons is a bug, from here http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/92862/toolstrip-always-draws-a-border-on-the-bottom-with-rendermode-system-and-docked-left-or-right I'll post the below, may be useful for another users. Thanks digEmAll.

Comment: @user705654: interesting, and you can also apply that code to the one posted by HansPassant ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can reassign the Renderer property for the ToolStrip to create your own renderer.  Overriding the OnRenderSplitButtonBackground() is however very painful, a split button has a lot of doodahs that need to be painted and the stock painter methods are private.  The easier approach in your case is to override the color table.  Make it look like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        toolStrip1.Renderer = new MyRenderer();
    }

    private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer {
        public MyRenderer() : base(new MyColors()) {}
    }

    private class MyColors : ProfessionalColorTable {
        public override Color ButtonSelectedGradientBegin {
            get { return Color.Black; }
        }
        public override Color ButtonSelectedGradientMiddle {
            get { return Color.Black; }
        }
        public override Color ButtonSelectedGradientEnd {
            get { return Color.Black; }
        }
    }
}
```